# Datasource not returning data from onSuccess function

Tags: knockout.js, devexpress, phonejs

I'm getting an array off 100 objects as expected from this datasource when I stick the debugger on `mapped` by `deferred.resolve(mapped);`. However it's not transferring that into my dxTileView.

It really shouldn't be a binding issue as it's displaying the `noDataText` instead of an error.

Anyone have any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
        load: function (loadOptions) {
            if (loadOptions.refresh) {
                var deferred = new $.Deferred();
                callService("LoadEmployees", {
                    device: lStorage.getDeviceID()
                }, function (result) {
                    serverActive = true;
                    var mapped = $.map(result, function (data) {
                        return {
                            info: '',
                            id: data.EmployeeNo,
                            name: data.Name,
                            widthRatio: 2,
                            status: data.Status,
                            lastProject: data.LastProject,
                            lastStart: data.LastStart,
                            lastCostCenter: data.LastCostCenter,
                            lastScan: data.LastScan,
                            projectName: data.LastProject ? data.LastProject.Name : null,
                            inBreak: data.Status == 2,
                            working: data.Status == 1,
                            notWorking: data.Status == 0,
                            aktivProjectId: null
                        }
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(mapped);
                });
                return deferred.promise();
            }
        },
    });
```

And the html is here:

```
<div id="mitarbeiter" data-bind="dxTileView: {
           noDataText:noDataText, 
           height:tileWidgetHeight,
           itemClickAction:tileClick,
           baseItemHeight: 80, 
           baseItemWidth: 100,
           dataSource:dataSource, 
           showScrollbar: showScrollbar
      }">

    <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name: 'item' } " data-bind="css: {working:working,inBreak:inBreak}" class="tile">
      <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
      <p data-bind="text: projectName"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is correct, just remove the condition `if (loadOptions.refresh)` in the `load` method.

See fields of the `loadOptions` in the docs http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Library/CustomStore/Configuration/?version=14_2#load

I would also use `map` function of dataSource instead of manual mapping (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/7w4or9Ls/))

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    load: function (loadOptions) {
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();

        callService("LoadEmployees", {
            device: lStorage.getDeviceID()
        }, function (result) {
            serverActive = true;
            deferred.resolve(result);
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    },
    map: function(data) {
        return {
            info: '',
            id: data.EmployeeNo,
            name: data.Name,
            widthRatio: 2,
            status: data.Status,
            lastProject: data.LastProject,
            lastStart: data.LastStart,
            lastCostCenter: data.LastCostCenter,
            lastScan: data.LastScan,
            projectName: data.LastProject ? data.LastProject.Name : null,
            inBreak: data.Status == 2,
            working: data.Status == 1,
            notWorking: data.Status == 0,
            aktivProjectId: null
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ugh, I spend so long looking through the docs of 14.2 but it never occurred to me to look at the load options (refresh was in v13). Thanks again, everything working ok, answer marked as correct.